# Как нарисовать линию из точки А в точку В?

Tags: qml

Пытаюсь нарисовать линию из точки А в точку В, но почему-то не рисует.

**Код:**

```
Window {
    // вот тут переменные first tochka and dwa tochka
    property var cliced_x0 : 0;
    property var cliced_y0 : 0;
    property var cliced_x1 : 0;
    property var cliced_y1 : 0;
    property var bool_cliced : false;
    ...
    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        ...
        onPaint: {
            ...
            var ctx = getContext('2d')
            ctx.lineWidth = 1.5
            ctx.strokeStyle = canvas.color
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.moveTo(cliced_x0, cliced_y0)
            ctx.lineTo(cliced_x1, cliced_y1)
            ctx.stroke()
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: area
            anchors.fill: parent
            
            onClicked: {
                if (bool_cliced === false)
                {
                    cliced_x0 = mouseX;
                    cliced_y0 = mouseY;
                    bool_cliced = true;
                }
                if(bool_cliced === true)
                {
                    cliced_x1 = mouseX;
                    cliced_y1 = mouseY;
                    bool_cliced = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не нужно ли завершить closePath? И на всякий случай -  `ctx.strokeStyle = canvas.color` - не невидимый ли цвет получается?

Comment: @MBo должен быть черный цвет  , цвет по умолчанию черный. Заменил `ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";` увы не заработало :(

Comment: а closePath добавили перед stroke()?

Comment: @MBo             `ctx.closePath()` перед `ctx.stroke()` поставил и пересобрал увы не заработало :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[тут](https://forum.qt.io/topic/128117/how-to-draw-a-line-from-point-a-to-point-b-by-mouse-click/6) мне дали ответ

В место этого кода:

```
if (bool_cliced == false)
{
cliced_x0 = area.mouseX;
cliced_y0 = area.mouseY;
bool_cliced = true;
}
if(bool_cliced == true)
{
cliced_x1 = area.mouseX;
cliced_y1 = area.mouseY;
bool_cliced = false;
canvas.requestPaint()
}
```

нужен такой :

```
if (bool_cliced == false)
{
    cliced_x0 = area.mouseX;
    cliced_y0 = area.mouseY;
}
else
{
    cliced_x1 = area.mouseX;
    cliced_y1 = area.mouseY;
    canvas.requestPaint()
}
bool_cliced = !bool_cliced;
```

В общем логика был не та .  **При любом клике выполняются оба ифа !!! так как они оба были истинны** по этому и не отрисовывал